# Ruby: Difference between passing `&proc` and `proc` to a method

Tags: ruby

I have a bit of code modified slightly from a question on codeacademy. The code is :

```
def print_list(array, first = 1)
  counter = first
  array.each do |array|
    puts "#{yield counter} #{array}"
    counter = counter.next
  end
end

proc = Proc.new do |n|
  "[#{100*n}]:"
end

print_list ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"], 5, &proc
```

If I remove the & from the last line Ruby throws me an argument error. What is the purpose of the & here?

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the `&`, then `print_list` treats `proc` as a third argument to itself, instead of a block. The `&` symbol transforms the `Proc` object into a block, which is called inside `print_list` by the `yield` keyword.

More succinctly,
`proc` is just an argument, `&proc` is a reference to the block passed to the method.

You might find [this article](http://augustl.com/blog/2008/procs_blocks_and_anonymous_functions/) useful to understand the differences between proc and blocks

Comment: Does scope matter with &proc?

Comment: Procs are not different from variables when it comes to scope - it has to be within scope so that it can be referred to!

Answer (score 1):

The & indicates that the proc should be passed as a block.

Without it, the "proc" will just be another (third) parameter so you'll get the argument error (3 for 2)

It's possible to pass it without the & and use it in your print_list method directly as a proc... but first can't be optional then.  You'll need to pass first or at the very least nil.

```
def print_list(array, first, proc)
  counter = first || 1
  array.each do |array|
    puts "#{proc.call counter} #{array}"
    counter = counter.next
  end
end
```